# Architectural Design Patterns for Augmented Reality Applications

Tags: wpf, xaml, augmented-reality

Are there any white papers or books on design patterns dealing with Augmented Reality systems?

**Intent:**

- HoloLens Development

**Note:**

- I am not confident that applying MVVM will map well to Augmented Reality applications.
- I'm curious if **ALL** Augmented Relaity applications are SPAs.

Comment: As far as I know, there aren't really any good papers or book.  While many AR apps are SPA's, that's largely because it's sufficiently hard to deal with AR tools, that most apps are pretty trivial.   However, AR is just "overlaying content on a view of the world" ... you can use whatever design patterns you want.  In our Argon system (which uses web tech for content), we are trying to make it possible to use any web patterns.

Comment: BTW, I'm sure HoloLens will come with it's own set of design patters for AR.  MS will be revealing the APIs at their Build conference.

Answer (score 0):

As we now know after the Build15 conference Holoens will Support all Windows 10 Universal Apps. So the main jist will be to adapt developing for Windows 10.

Currently no further Infos are known on the [HoloLens Developer Page](https://www.microsoft.com/microsoft-hololens/en-us/developers)

See also the [FAQ](https://www.microsoft.com/microsoft-hololens/en-us/developers#faq)